# Propper JavaFX thread implementation

Tags: multithreading, javafx, concurrency, task

In my GUI I have a TableView that should show a list of loaded files, after a class called PathGetter has finished loading them into an ObservableArrayList, but I just can't implement the task correctly.

This is the important part in the JavaFX class

```
browseButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            File dir = folderPicker.showDialog(bwindow);
            if(dir != null){
                directoryLocation.setText(String.valueOf(dir));
                bottom.getChildren().add(new javafx.scene.control.Label("Loading Tracks"));
                //PathGetter.getPath(directoryLocation.getText());
                PathGetter task = new PathGetter(directoryLocation.getText());
                Thread th = new Thread(task);
                try {
                    pjesme = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                selection.setItems(pjesme);
                chSelAll.setDisable(false);
                chSelIncomplete.setDisable(false);
                chSelNoCover.setDisable(false);
            }

        });
```

And this is the class that should work in

```
public class PathGetter extends Task<ObservableList<Track>> {

    static boolean getSubDirs;
    static ArrayList <Track> allFiles;
    public static int trNr = 0;
    private static String fullPath;

    public PathGetter(String path) {
        fullPath = path;
    }

    public static int getTrNr() {
        return trNr;
    }

    public static void setTrNr(int trNr) {
        PathGetter.trNr = trNr;
    }

    public static boolean isSupported (File f){
        //supported file types
        if(String.valueOf(f).endsWith(".flac") || String.valueOf(f).endsWith(".mp3") || String.valueOf(f).endsWith(".aiff") || String.valueOf(f).endsWith(".ogg") || String.valueOf(f).endsWith(".mp4")){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected ObservableList<Track> call() throws Exception {
        getSubDirs = Browser.chSubDirs.isSelected();
        allFiles = new ArrayList<Track>();
        Queue<File> dirs = new LinkedList<File>();
        dirs.add(new File(fullPath));
        while (!dirs.isEmpty()) {
            for (File f : dirs.poll().listFiles()) {
                if (f.isDirectory() && getSubDirs == true) {
                    dirs.add(f);
                } else if (f.isFile() && isSupported(f)) {
                    allFiles.add(new Track(f));
                    setTrNr(getTrNr()+1);
                }
            }
        }
        ObservableList<Track> returnList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(allFiles);
        return returnList;
    }
}
```

I don't understand how to make the TableView wait for the task to be finished, without blocking the entire JavaFX thread, which basically defeats the purpose of a task. I want it to be able to show progress in real time, simply by displaying the number of added tracks at that moment.

Comment: Question: you seem to be tracking a count of files processed in `trNr`. Is this the value you want to progressively display in the UI? Do you have a way of knowing before you start the processing of the files what the total is going to be? Without that you obviously cannot do any kind of "percent complete" tracking.

Comment: @James_D There is no way of knowing the total number of files beforehand, unless I want to count them first, which I really don't want right now. I just want to make a simple Label that shows how many files were added so far, so the user knows the app is doing something. But I think that's the easy part, I don't understand these answers about the main problem of hanging the UI thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two threading rules specific to JavaFX:

1. Any changes to the UI **must** be made on the FX Application Thread. Not doing this will either cause `IllegalStateException`s to be thrown at runtime, or may put the UI in an inconsistent state, potentially causing unpredicatable behavior at arbitrary points in the future.
2. Any code that takes a long time to run **should** be performed on a background thread. Not doing so will cause the UI to become unresponsive while that code is running.

Additionally, there is a general rule about threading:

Care must be taken when accessing mutable state in multiple threads. In particular, operations in a given thread should be ensured to be atomic, and special care may need to be taken to ensure changes to the state of the data made in one thread are visible to another thread.

Getting this last part correct is particularly challenging. Additionally, when using a background thread in a UI environment, you almost always want to share the results of the process, and sometimes data that is computed during the process, between the background thread and the UI thread. Because this is challenging, JavaFX provides a `Task` class (and some other related classes) that take care of the trickier parts of this in order to cover most use cases.

In particular, the `Task` class exposes various properties (including `state`, `progress`, `message`, and `value`), along with thread-safe `updateXXX` methods. The update methods are safe to be called from any thread, and will both ensure the properties are updated on the UI thread, and throttle the number of updates to them (coalescing updates together essentially if they occur within the time the UI is updated). This means it is safe to call the `update` methods from the background thread, and observe the properties in the UI thread. Additionally, you can call these methods as often as you like without "flooding" the UI thread and causing it to become unresponsive that way.

The `Task` class also exposes handlers for transitioning from one state to another, such as `setOnSucceeded` (invoked when the task completes normally) and `setOnFailed` (invoked when the task throws an exception). These are also handled on the FX Application Thread.

Your task subclass can:

1. Use the message property to update the number of tracks processed
2. Return the list of tracks generated

From the UI code, you can bind the text of a label to the message property. You can also use on `onSucceeded` handler to update the UI when the task completes.

To ensure you don't share mutable state between threads, other than that which is properly managed by the `Task` machinery, you should properly encapsulate your class. This means not exposing any state that is manipulated by the task itself. None of your state should be `static` (and there is no obvious reason you would want to do this anyway).

So I would write the task as follows:

```
public class PathGetter extends Task<ObservableList<Track>> {

    private final boolean getSubDirs;
    private final String fullPath;

    public PathGetter(String path, boolean getSubDirs) {
        fullPath = path;
        this.getSubDirs = getSubDirs ;
    }

    public static boolean isSupported (File f){
        String fileName = f.toString();
        //supported file types
        return fileName.endsWith(".flac") 
               || fileName.endsWith(".mp3")  
               || fileName.endsWith(".aiff") 
               || fileName.endsWith(".ogg") 
               || fileName.endsWith(".mp4") ;
    }

    @Override
    protected ObservableList<Track> call() throws Exception {

        List<Track> allFiles = new ArrayList<Track>();
        Queue<File> dirs = new LinkedList<File>();
        dirs.add(new File(fullPath));
        while (!dirs.isEmpty()) {
            for (File f : dirs.poll().listFiles()) {
                if (f.isDirectory() && getSubDirs) {
                    dirs.add(f);
                } else if (f.isFile() && isSupported(f)) {
                    allFiles.add(new Track(f));
                    updateMessage("Number of tracks processed: "+allFiles.size());
                }
            }
        }
        ObservableList<Track> returnList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(allFiles);
        return returnList;
    }
}
```

Now from the UI you can do something like:

```
browseButton.setOnAction(event -> {
    File dir = folderPicker.showDialog(bwindow);
    if(dir != null){
        directoryLocation.setText(String.valueOf(dir));
        Label label = new Label("Loading Tracks");
        bottom.getChildren().add(label);

        PathGetter task = new PathGetter(directoryLocation.getText(), Browser.chSubDirs.isSelected());
        Thread th = new Thread(task);

        // keep label showing message from task:
        label.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());

        task.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
            selection.setItems(task.getValue());
            chSelAll.setDisable(false);
            chSelIncomplete.setDisable(false);
            chSelNoCover.setDisable(false);
        });

        task.setOnFailed(e -> {
            // handle exception ...

            // and log it
            task.getException().printStackTrace();
        });

        chSelAll.setDisable(true);
        chSelIncomplete.setDisable(true);
        chSelNoCover.setDisable(true);

        // make sure thread doesn't prevent application exit:
        th.setDaemon(true);

        // set it going:
        th.start();

    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for making a proper detailed response, I will make the code changes tomorrow and give the update then.

Comment: I've implemented the code and can confirm that it works correctly. I'm sure this thread will help people with the same problem cause I wasn't able to find a proper response before.

Answer (score -2):

You could add a listener to your ObservableArrayList.

```
         pjesme.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Track>() {
            @Override
        public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Track> c) {
            /* Do your Stuff in the gui. Like having the status bar or things */
        }
         });
```

After you have added the listener you just hand it to the constructor

```
       public PathGetter(String path, ObservableList<Track> pjesme) {
          fullPath = path;
          this.pjesme = pjesme;
       }
```

and alter the ObersvableList in your PathGetter class. So everytime you add something to your List the eventlistener will get invoked and you get the chance to update stuff in your GUI.

Comment: But now the problem is that you're modifying the list in one thread and observing it in another. The implementation of `ObservableList` is not thread safe.... So to make this work you would need to wrap all calls in the task that modify the list with `Platform.runLater()`. As the [task docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) say: "WARNING: Do not pass mutable state to a Task and then operate on it from a background thread. ".